# How to use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter in @RestController parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-web

I have the following restcontroller, and would like to get-query the controller with `thedate=2016-08-08` format.

It should be automatically converted to `java.time.LocalDate`.
But my `XmlAdapter` is not working. Why?

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class LocalDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return LocalDate.parse(v, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDate v) throws Exception {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(date);
    }
}

@RestController
public class MyServlet {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   private String test(RestParams p) {

   }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RestParams {
        @Valid
        @NotNull
        @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false)
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
        private LocalDate thedate;
}
```

Result:

> 'thedate': Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String]
>   to required type [java.time.LocalDate] for property 'thedate'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.Valid
>   @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
>   @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
>   @javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter
>   java.time.LocalDate] for value '2016-08-08'; nested exception is
>   java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-08-08' could not
>   be parsed at index 2

Comment: Have you tried debugging into `marshal` and `unmarshal` to see whether they are called at all?

Comment: Yes, my adapter seems not being called at all. As if it was not registered. But why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's not working, but I solved it using a spring annotation:

```
   @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
   private java.time.LocalDate thedate;
```